Mold Under Hardwood Flooring From Leaking Water
The water tank cracked on my toilet and it wasn't noticed for a week. There was damage to my Cherrywood flooring with cupping and black stains between boards. Have been running a heater in bathroom to hopefully dry the floor but now I'm smelling mold (and it's making me sick) I know I'll have to have the floor repaired with new flooring but the mold needs to be gotten rid of fast. What would happen if I flooded it with white vinegar?

vinegar will not do it, use bleach

And it does not need to be flooded.  A simple spray bottle will do.

You can just mop the floors with a dilution of bleach, and that will take care of the problem. Bleach is the most effective treatment against mold, and most -- if not all -- chemicals sold in stores to treat mold are just repackaged bleach.
The black stains between the boards are unlikely to be mold. Most likely they are just the normal discoloration of wood when it gets soaked.
It is very unlikely that the subfloor has so much mold that it is affecting you. For mold to affect the breathing air, it has to release loads of spores. This is unlikely to happen in such a short time, and even if the subfloor has mold, the floor above will seal the spores.
A dehumidifier will also work a lot better than just turning on the heat. If you are sensitive to mold, a dehumidifier is a good investment.

Hydrogen peroxide is better than bleach, but even better would be Concrobium. Google it. Made of 3 salts. Non toxic. Don't know about under floorboards but the website might have info on that. Or call the company.
I don't work for them, just learned about it through research due to my mold sensitivity. I've used it. No nasty fumes. No feeling like I'm spraying something unhealthy. I used it on everything in my LR after having black mold in heat exchanger.
